# 3 Dimensional Tic Tac Toe prints only one dimension

Tags: java

I'm starting on a program to make a 3D tic tac toe game, and am running into a few problems. The game is supposed to be 4x4x4. I'm not sure why the multiple dimensions are not being printed, and I'm also not sure why my entered value isn't appearing on the one level that shows. Code below. Any help would be awesome. Thanks!

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int draw = 64;
        int n = 0;

        int board[][][] = new int[4][4][4];
        while (n < draw) {
        System.out.println("Type your move as one three digit number(lrc)");
        int input = scan.nextInt();
        int level = input / 100;
        int row = input % 100 / 10;
        int column = input % 10;
        System.out.println(level);
        System.out.println(row);
        System.out.println(column);

            board[level][row][column] = 1;


            for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--) { //level

                for (int h = 3; h >= 0; h--) { //row

                    for (int temp = h; temp >= 0; temp--) {
                        System.out.print(" ");
                    }

                    System.out.print(i + "" + h + "  ");

                    for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++) { //column

                        if (board[i][h][j] == 0) {
                            System.out.print("_ ");
                        }
                        if (board[i][h][j] == 1) {
                            System.out.print("X ");
                            n++;
                        }
                        if (board[i][h][j] == 5) {
                            System.out.print("O ");
                            n++;
                        }
                    }

                    System.out.println();

                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println("\n   0 1 2 3");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code? Are you getting any errors while running the program? If so, then post the stack trace

Comment: If an output is not what you expected, have you considered debuging your code?

Comment: I wasn't getting any errors, the output just wasn't what I expected. I'm trying to debug, but I'm pretty new to programming and my instructor doesn't teach us well and leaves out certain things like debugging.

Comment: I edited the code, firstly I fixed the for loop with the temp variable, that wasn't allowing the other dimensions to be printed. Secondly, the board pieces were being put int he wrong spots because I was decrementing through the columns in the arrays instead of incrementing. But the board showing on the output is a little messed up. There are skipped lines every now and again. Not sure why they're there. I'll keep looking to fix.

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
 for (int temp = h; h > 0; h--) {
```

you are decrementing `h` rather than `temp` so in the loops below the value of `h` will always be `1`

After this change

change `for (int temp = h; temp >= 0; temp--) {
                    System.out.println(" ");
                }`

to simply `System.out.println(" ");`

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. My tutor said to decrement h, maybe he was wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Could you possibly check my new code and see why the printed board is a little messed up? The board has some random spacing in it between rows and I'm not sure why they're there. I upvotted

Comment: I need that for loop for my assignment requirements, so that the board is slightly offset to make it more visually appealing. I fixed the my previous problem, code updated. Now I need to put in computer play, with the play conditions and the conditions of when the game ends. For this, how do I transverse through the lines and sum up the horizontal, vertical and diagonal columns? I'm thinking of creating a computerPlay method, where it'll look for good spots to play in the board passed into the method. Any thoughts? Thanks for the help!